# AngularJS Controller depending on URL parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**EDIT:** Added $routeProvider and $routeParams, but $routeParams.productId is always undefined. It was my initial try, but I thought it was the wrong way. Anyway it does not work for the moment.

I start to learn AngularJS and I have a very simple question :
Depending on ID contained in URL, I would like to display different BD record.

```
...
<div ng-app=MyApp>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{ record }}
  </div>
</div>
...
```

My Javascript file :

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);

MyApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/get/:productId', {
       controller: 'MyCtrl'
    });
}])

MyApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$routeParams','$http',
  function($scope,$routeParams,$http) {
     $http.get("/get/"+$routeParams.productId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.record = data;
     });
}])
```

I tried to use $routeProvider and $routeParams without success.

Thank you in advance,
Bill

Comment: It's totally possible that "get" in your path has a name collision, since it's also an HTTP verb and an $http method.

Answer (score 10):

you need 2 things , the $routeParams injected in your controller and create a valid route with the get method

```
    MyApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$http',"$routeParams",
        function($scope,$http,$routeParams) {
             $http.get("/get/"+$routeParams.productId).success(function(data) {
                 $scope.record = data;
        });
    };
```

Comment: What I am missing is how implement the glue linking ID used on URL, and $routeParams.productId. I have tried something like $routeProvider.when('/get/:productId', { controller: 'MyCtrl' }) without success.

Comment: Updated with $routeProvider

Comment: You need to install ngRoute for this to work: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute